# Android application throws the error that it has stopped working, android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

I am trying to create an asset manager for android that will open text from a text file and and image. However, when I try to run it, it says it has stopped working. Using the LogCat, this is the error I can find that I think may be causing the issue:

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Here is the code for the main activity:

```
package AssetDemo.eoghanalphagame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Asset_Activity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Define the type of activity we want created - no title, full screen
    // and keep the screen on whilst it is visible. This needs to be
    // completed before any components
    // are inflated.
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    // Set the content view up to hold a single fragment
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_asset_);

    // Add whatever fragment is appropriate for the derived call - calling
    // the overloaded createFragment() method to retrieve the fragment.
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_asset_ImageView);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = createFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_asset_ImageView, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}

/**
 * Get the fragment for this particular activity
 * 
 * @return Fragment for this activity
 */
public Fragment createFragment(){
    return new AssetTestFragment();
}
}
```

Here is the code for the fragment:

```
package AssetDemo.eoghanalphagame;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AssetTestFragment extends Fragment {


@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{


    //inflate the view
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_asset_, container, false);

    //get assest manager for current activity and load in text and image

    AssetManager assetManager = getActivity().getAssets();
    String text = loadText(assetManager, "Text/test.txt");
    Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmap(assetManager, "Images/TheVanishingOfEthanCarter_logo_t.png");

    //Display the text
    TextView outputTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_asset_TextView);
    outputTextView.setText(text != null ? text: "ERROR: Could not open text file.");

    //Display the bitmap
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_asset_ImageView);
    if(bitmap != null)
    {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    return view;

}


//Create the loadText method

private String loadText(AssetManager assetManager, String asset)
{
    String text = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try
    {
        //Try to open text file
        inputStream = assetManager.open(asset);

        //Load in Text in 4k chunks
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] chunk = new byte[4096];
        int len = 0;
        while((len = inputStream.read(chunk)) > 0)
            byteStream.write(chunk, 0, len);

        //convert and return as a UFT8 String
        text = new String(byteStream.toByteArray(), "UTF8");

    }catch (IOException e) 
    {

        Log.e(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.LOG_TAG),
                "Error loading text asset: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally 
    {
        if(inputStream != null)
            try
        {
                inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {/*returns a null}*/

        }

    }

    return text;
}

//Load the Bitmap


private Bitmap loadBitmap(AssetManager assetManager, String asset)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try
    {
        //Try to open the bitmap
        inputStream = assetManager.open(asset);

        //Setup load prefrences
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        //Load the Bitmap
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);

    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.LOG_TAG),
                "Error Loading Bitmap: " +e.getMessage());
    } finally 
    {
        if(inputStream != null)
            try
            {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) 
            {/*returns a null*/

            }
    }
    return bitmap;
}

}
```

And here is the XML file that the TextView and ImageView are created in:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="AssetDemo.eoghanalphagame.Asset_Activity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_asset_ImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fragment_asset_TextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_asset_TextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_asset_TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want to know is why it is not working and what needs to be changed to make it work. I have created all the files I have referenced. I feel like it is something simple I am missing, but being new to android development I have no idea what.

Thanks

Comment: The `FragmentTransaction#add()` method expects the ID for a ViewGroup, not your ImageView. Also, you shouldn't be using the same layout for both the Activity and Fragment.

Comment: @MikeM. i think you should post this as an answer, just my thoughts.. anyway..

Comment: @MikeM. I am using the same Layou. I am using fragment_asset. And where is this FragmentTransaction#add() method. Its not in my code.

Comment: The transaction happens on this line: `fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_asset_ImageView, fragment).commit();`. The first argument in the `add()` method should be a ViewGroup ID.

Comment: @MikeM. where would I find the the ViewGroup ID's. Apart from the two assets for Text and Image the only other ID's I have are container and action_settings, and the application still stops with them

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes  a build after a "clean" will make things OK.

Because if you change the view's ID , the mentioned Exception may come.